# Exporting / Importing vanilla Javascript files after building does not render on html | Opposite of what occurs happens instead

Tags: javascript

This is the file I want to export

```js
/* import IUrl from "../../interfaces/url.interface"; */

class BaseUrl {
  private static baseUrl: string = "http://localhost:53134";
  private static discordLoginUrl: string =
    "";

  public static getDiscordLoginLink(): string {
    if (window.location.href.includes("onrender")) {
      this.discordLoginUrl = "";
    } else if (window.location.href.includes("replit.dev")) {
      this.discordLoginUrl =
        "";
    } else if (window.location.href.includes("replit.app")) {
      this.discordLoginUrl =
        "";
    }

    return this.discordLoginUrl;
  }

  public static getBaseUrl(): any {
    if (window.location.href.includes("onrender")) {
      this.baseUrl = "h";
    } else if (window.location.href.includes("replit.dev")) {
      this.baseUrl =
        "";
    } else if (window.location.href.includes("replit.app")) {
      this.baseUrl =
        "";
    }

    return {
      cryptoUrl: this.baseUrl + "/crypto",
      baseUrl: this.baseUrl,
      discordUrl: this.baseUrl + "/discord-server",
    };
  }
}

const myVariable = "Hello from baseurl";

// baseurl.js
export const treat = {
  hello: "Hello from baseurl",
  ok: BaseUrl,
};
```

I build the file with tsc and is located in the dist directory

```
    <script type="module">
      import * as baseurlModule from "./dist/webpage/constants/baseurl.js";
      console.log("here is r: ", baseurlModule.treat);
    </script>
```

I want to use it here for example or even another typescript file, then compile it, but it would not work at all, no matter if I change the tsconfig, use exports instead of module.exports, and I know this is client side code. However, I have no idea the reasoning for it reading it as node.js file. I am able to only use one file at a time in HTML, but could not interact with each other

Another example

```
import { treat } from "../constants/baseurl";

import fetchfromclient from "./fetchfromclient";
window.onload = async () => {
  const { cryptoUrl, baseUrl, discordUrl }: IUrl =
    treat.ok.getBaseUrl() as IUrl;

//...
```

I have tried to use different type of javascript, whether it is type of module, export or import, nothing seems to work on using them interchangeably with each other.